# Convert an amount of seconds into a formatted string using midp/blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, midp

I'm trying to convert an amount of seconds into a formatted string using midp

Below is code I'm using, the problem is that when I run this on a device (BlackBerry), 2 hours are being appended. So - 
formatSecondsAsDuration(1000) returns "00:02:01" 
What I expect is "00:00:01"

I think this is occuring since SimpleDateFormat is using my locale ?
I am unable to use the method setTimeZone to set the timezone to UTC which I think could fix the issue.

```
public static String formatSecondsAsDuration(long second) {

    Date date = new Date(second);

     return new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(date);

}
```

I have already asked a similar question - [Convert int val to format "HH:MM:SS" using JDK1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581281/convert-int-val-to-format-hhmmss-using-jdk1-4) But have since found was not fully suitable

Comment: You could have added a reference to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581281/convert-int-val-to-format-hhmmss-using-jdk1-4/). This would at least save others from wasting unnecessary effort by providing same answers.

Comment: @mindas, apologies, I've updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about something really simple like:

```
public static String formatSecondsAsDuration(long seconds) {
    long hour = seconds / 60 / 60;
    long min = (seconds / 60) - (hour * 60);
    long sec = seconds - (min * 60) - (hour * 60 * 60);

    return (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour + ":" + 
           (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min + ":" +
           (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec;
}
```

Just make sure you actually pass seconds (as indicated by the parameter name), or else modify the code above to handle milliseconds if that's what you're actually needing.

**EDIT**:
I just ran across this method today that looks like it does exactly what you want and is already built-in to the BB API: [DateTimeUtilities.formatElapsedTime()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/util/DateTimeUtilities.html#formatElapsedTime%28long,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20boolean%29)